# jquery.dropdown.js required not working

Tags: jquery, html, web

I'm using the `jquery.dropdown.js` plugin. 
My problem is there is no notification appear when submitting the form, leaving the required select tag with no value.

html:

```
<div class="dropdown-sin-1" style="margin-top: -15px;">
        <select name="" placeholder="" required>      
            <option value="" disabled selected></option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
            <option value="6">6</option>
            <option value="7">7</option>
        </select>
        </div>
```

js:

```
$('.dropdown-sin-1').dropdown({
  readOnly: false,
  limitCount: Infinity,
  input: '<input type="text" maxLength="20" placeholder="Search">',
  data: [],
  searchable: true,
  searchNoData: '<li style="color:#ddd">No Results</li>',
  choice: function () {}
});
```

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tbge7f2m/

Comment: add your html output or fiddle link @John

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- In your fiddle, the order of the libraries is incorrect. You have to load jQuery before jquery.dropdown.js.
- I'm not sure whether it's a bug, but you are not allowed empty `value` in `select` `option`, so I've added a space `value=" "`. (If you want to check for emptiness, you can just test for a single space)
- You have to add `style="display:none"` to hide the original select box.
- Maybe you want to remove the `data: []`, as that's for generating options dynamically, which is not what you are doing here.

Fully working example:

```js
$('.dropdown-sin-1').dropdown({
  readOnly: false,
  limitCount: Infinity,
  input: '<input type="text" maxLength="20" placeholder="Search">',
  searchable: true,
  searchNoData: '<li style="color:#ddd">No Results</li>',
  choice: function() {}
});
```

```html
<link href="https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Searchable-Multi-select-jQuery-Dropdown/jquery.dropdown.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Searchable-Multi-select-jQuery-Dropdown/jquery.dropdown.js"></script>

<form method="post">
  <div class="dropdown-sin-1">
    <select style="display:none" name="" placeholder="" required>
      <option value=" " disabled selected></option>
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
      <option value="5">5</option>
      <option value="6">6</option>
      <option value="7">7</option>
      <option value="8">8</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit">
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: How to Use it with the dynamic server-side data.